# How do I permanently fix a GRUB partition off by one error?

Tags: grub, multi-boot, macbook-pro, refit

I have a MacBook Pro set up to triple boot with rEFIt and GRUB. (I had to go through GRUB to get Windows 7 to boot, but that's tolerable.) I upgraded to Lion which added a new partition for the recovery feature. This also causes GRUB to boot to a rescue prompt. Running set shows:

```
prefix=(hd0,gpt5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt5
```

If I run the following commands:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt6)
insmod normal
normal
```

the usual GRUB menu shows up and I can boot into whichever OS I want. I got into the Ubuntu partition and checked out the `grub.cfg` file and it was setting the root to gpt5. I ran the `sudo update-grub` command.  This changed the value in the cfg file to gpt6.  However GRUB still boots into the rescue prompt and set still shows the initial root and prefix values. How do I make this permanent?

Comment: I am facing the same problem? Anyone could solve it?

Comment: Have you tried [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) with `sudo update-grub` ? Some people also advocate using [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) instead of grub.

Comment: As a sidenote. You're not supposed to edit `grub.cfg` by hand, it gets regenerated everytime you run `update-grub`. Can we also get the the layout of the disk (`fdisk -l`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grub is probably dropping to the console because the partition layout has changed since grub was first installed.  Now that you have updated grub.cfg, re-installing grub should fix it.  Boot into your ubuntu system the same way you did in order to run update-grub.  From there, do a grub-install:

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

(Replacing X with your device, in your case it looks like it is probably /dev/sda.)

Comment: Hey! I want to award the bounty to this answer. But it seems there was on expiry on awarding it too. How can I award the bouty to this answer?

Comment: I did that in a sort of round about way.  I upgraded to 11.10 and all is well.

Comment: How do I know what is the device I should use (the X)?

Comment: @becko, you can run `$ lsblk` to see your /dev/sdX (SSD should be something like /dev/nvme0n1). The grub-install command should point to the disk, not the partition!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. grub rescue fix the partition on sda1 instead of sda6. System booting with succeed. But if I reboot the system, the root=(hd0,msdos1) changed back to msdos6.

grub-install /dev/sd1 make system staying on boot menu forever.

Question, where grub exactly get the root setting?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1199136)