# I typed "sudo update-grub sudo && grub-install /dev/sda" but still I have to "set root=~ set prefix ~ insmod normal;normal;" to go to login display

Tags: debian, grub

As I boot my computer , I always have to type the following to go inside the login display of the os.

```
set root=(hd1,gpt2);

set prefix=(hd1,gpt2)/boot/grub;

insmod normal;

normal;
```

I want to set the configuration(s) as default to avoid typing the above codes again and again.

I use the debian-based operating system and found [the article of the solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867519/grub-rescue-setting-boot-and-prefix-again-and-again) which exactly tackles my current problem.

Brief solution which I quote is as below.

```
sudo update-grub;

sudo grub-install /dev/sda;
 
reboot;
```

The results which were obtained typing the above 2 commands are as below.

[image]

[image]

Seemingly no such error was found but as I reboot, the same GRUB menu appears even I've done the 2 commands...

[This solution](https://superuser.com/questions/419876/grub-reinstall-after-partition-name-change)  and [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/313557/how-do-i-permanently-fix-a-grub-partition-off-by-one-error)  failed.

What can I do for next?

I've done the below 4 commands and got the below results .

```
efibootmgr -v;

tree -a /boot/efi;

lsblk;

sudo tree -a /boot/efi;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is `/dev/sdb` a USB drive? Does it boot and lead you to the same problem if you unplug drive first? If it does, perhaps try to `sudo mv /boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi{,.bak}` and then see if `grub-install` will actually install `grubx64.efi` back in `/boot/efi/ubuntu/`. If it does, see if `sudo mv /boot/efi/kali/grubx64.efi{,.kali}; sudo cp /boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/kali/` helps (in case shim failed somehow and the UEFI turns to the kali entry/executable). Maybe also pastebin `/boot/efi/ububtu/grub.cfg` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: If `grub-install` does not put another `grubx64.efi` back to `/boot/efi/ubuntu/`, make sure you rename the old one back with `sudo mv /boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi{.bak,}` before you perform a reboot.

Comment: I guess ```/dev/sdb``` is a usb and the format of it is fat32 .

Comment: Even unplugged the usb , I encountered the same problem.

Comment: I've done ```sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi{,.bak}``` instead of ```sudo mv /boot/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi{,.bak}``` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STEP1: Take the archive of the contents of the os.

STEP2 : Install the server version of ubuntu into the ssd(which means the original os will be deleted).

STEP3 : Reinstall the os which you really want to reinstall .

STEP4 : Solved!